# How do I tell Firefox and Vivaldi to trust a certificate authority or how do I get around their connection?

Tags: internet

On another question, I was told to do one of two things:

> You basically have two options here:
>
> Trust your internet provider and digital reflection to snoop on you
>   “responsibly” without exposing you to security risks. In that case you
>   can ask Firefox to trust their certificate authority for all secured
>   connections. It's possible to apply this trust system-wide.
>
> Don't trust them and ask them to stop snooping on you or find a way
>   around their connection interception with a VPN or equivalent.

How do I do these on Firefox and Vivaldi 32-bit?